# stored function in postgres causing the time out

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I have written a stored function in postgres. When I am running it, it is running for forever.

I am not sure why it is taking too much time even with 1 day data. Idk what is causing the issue.

Could have any one have a look and provide some feedback what it the issue here.

```
CREATE FUNCTION schema.delete_allHistoryRecord()
    RETURNS text
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    VOLATILE
AS $BODY$
DECLARE

    -- get the 15 old days transaction_history
     transaction_object_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT * from
     (SELECT * FROM schema.transaction
     WHERE start_time < (NOW() - INTERVAL '15 days')
     UNION SELECT * FROM schema.transaction_history
     WHERE start_time < (NOW() - INTERVAL '15 days')) trans 
     join schema.transaction_object_history hist
     on hist.transaction_row_id = trans.row_id limit 500;

     transaction_older_than_15_days schema.transaction%ROWTYPE;

    -- get the 90 old days project_history
    project_history_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM schema.project_history
    WHERE created_at < (now() - INTERVAL '90 Days');

    project_history_older_than_90_days schema.project_history%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN

  OPEN transaction_object_cursor;

  LOOP

    FETCH transaction_object_cursor INTO transaction_older_than_15_days;

    EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;

    DELETE FROM schema.transaction_object_history
    WHERE transaction_row_id = transaction_older_than_15_days.row_id;

  END LOOP;

  CLOSE transaction_object_cursor;

  OPEN project_history_cursor;

  LOOP

    FETCH project_history_cursor INTO project_history_older_than_90_days;

    EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;

    -- delete old data from project_user_history
    DELETE FROM schema.project_user_history
    WHERE project_id = project_history_older_than_90_days.project_id;

    DELETE FROM schema.project_object_history
    WHERE project_row_id  = project_history_older_than_90_days.row_id;

    DELETE FROM schema.transaction_history
    WHERE project_id = project_history_older_than_90_days.project_id;

    -- delete old data from project_history
    DELETE FROM schema.project_history
    WHERE project_id = project_history_older_than_90_days.project_id;

  END LOOP;

  CLOSE project_history_cursor;
  RETURN 'Done';
END;
$BODY$;
```

Query returns the result very fast and also

```
SELECT * from
         (SELECT * FROM schema.transaction
         WHERE start_time < (NOW() - INTERVAL '15 days')
         UNION SELECT * FROM schema.transaction_history
         WHERE start_time < (NOW() - INTERVAL '15 days')) trans 
         join schema.transaction_object_history hist
         on hist.transaction_row_id = trans.row_id limit 500;
```

and also

```
    OPEN transaction_object_cursor;
        
          LOOP
        
            FETCH transaction_object_cursor INTO transaction_older_than_15_days;
        
            EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
        
            cnt:=cnt+1;
transaction_older_than_15_days.row_id;
        
          END LOOP;
        
          CLOSE transaction_object_cursor;
```

the count is returning 500, it means cursor is fetching the data. still not able to understand why it is looping forever while deleting the data.

Comment: Why are you looping like that? Wouldn't it be better to just dump the contents of these two queries (or rather just the IDs) into a temp table and then DELETE everything in one go, joining the contents of temp tables? This looks like some kind of procedural language code converted into PL/pgSQL, but it's definitely not optimal.

Comment: First you select the data (in a cursor) and when that is successful, you throw the data away. Then why did you select it in the first place? Skip the SELECT statements and delete it right away.

Comment: @MarcinJ Ok , I can try that , but my question is why it is looping forever , if it doesn't find any row it should end the loop. even i try deleting the single row by using limit 1 , still it is looping forever.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I looping the cursor and deleting the row in db.

Comment: @The_new_coder It's really hard to tell why exactly without having access to your db. Maybe one of the queries is preforming badly (`SELECT * ... UNION SELECT *` will have poor performance as UNION removes duplicates), maybe there are some deadlock issues or underlying triggers that cascade.

Comment: @MarcinJ any pointers where should start to check the deadlock situation.beacsue if I run the 

SELECT * from
     (SELECT * FROM schema.transaction
     WHERE start_time < (NOW() - INTERVAL '15 days')
     UNION SELECT * FROM schema.transaction_history
     WHERE start_time < (NOW() - INTERVAL '15 days')) trans 
     join schema.transaction_object_history hist
     on hist.transaction_row_id = trans.row_id limit 500;
it returns the result and if I counting the loop after removing the delete script it is returning the row count , means everything is working fine but delete script